# Set @JsonProperty name using Spring's Expression Language (from application properties)

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-el

Suppose I have a `Foo` class like this:

```
public class Foo {

    @JsonProperty("${PROPERTY_NAME_FROM_APP_PROPERTIES}")
    private String foo;
    
}
```

How would we achieve dynamic JSON property name using `SpEL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` and override Spring's default `ObjectMapper`:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Environment environment) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new ExpressionLanguageJacksonAnnotationIntrospector(environment));

        return mapper;
    }

    public static class ExpressionLanguageJacksonAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

        private final Environment environment;
        
        public ExpressionLanguageJacksonAnnotationIntrospector(Environment environment) {
            this.environment = environment;
        }

        @Override
        public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated annotated) {
            PropertyName name = super.findNameForSerialization(annotated);

            if (name == null) {
                return null;
            }

            return PropertyName.construct(environment.resolvePlaceholders(name.getSimpleName()), name.getNamespace());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is dangerous because it will ignore any other `ObjectMapper` customizations, which can be a lot in a Spring Boot application. Better would be to implement a `@Bean` method that returns `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` and customize the builder rather than override the entire `ObjectMapper`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot; the annotation is processed by Jackson, not Spring.

Comment: I can, however, modify the Jackson's `ObjectMapper` used by Spring to add a custom `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` to fetch those application properties, right?

Comment: I would assume so, yes, so it seems you already have an answer - so what's the real question?

Comment: I found the answer right after posting the question.